# Link issue under AIX with G++ 6.3

Tags: c++11, linker, g++, shared-libraries, aix

After some struggle, I must admit I need some external help on this linker issue. AIX will kill me otherwise.
I am striving to migrate our build from GCC 4.8.5 to GCC 6.3.0 under AIX 7.1:

```
> uname -a
AIX wreckmach 1 7 00F63B074C00
> oslevel
7.1.0.0
```

Now, all the compilation phase is going well, but at link stage things starts going messy. My compilation line is like the following (I removed includes directories and some internal defines):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wno-deprecated -g -pthread -shared -maix64 -gdwarf -g3 -O3 -fPIC -fPIC -I./some/includes -D_REENTRANT=1 -DAIX53=1 -DAIX=1 -DNDEBUG=1 -DSVR4=1 -D__VACPP_MULTI__=1 -DRS6000=1 myCppFile.cpp -c -o /home/me/migration/build.AIX71_GCC_60300_64/myCppFile.cpp.1.o
```

And my link line is

```
g++ -g -ggdb3 -pthread -maix64 -Wl,-brtl -Wl,-bhalt:5 -Wl,-bnodelcsect -Wl,-brtl,-bexpfull -shared /home/me/migration/build.AIX71_GCC_60300_64/myCppFile.cpp.1.o /home/me/migration/build.AIX71_GCC_60300_64/myOtherCppFile.cpp.1.o -o /home/me/migration/build.AIX71_GCC_60300_64/libtest.so -L/BUILD/SOFT/compilers/AIX71/GCC/60300/lib64 -lgcc_s -lstdc++ -lpthread
```

This gives me the following output:

```
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
collect2: error: ld returned 8 exit status
```

By adding the -bnoquiet options, I got :

```
(ld): save SRE .
SAVE: Section sizes = 69976+5192+280 (0x11158+0x1448+0x118 hex)
SAVE: Size of TOC: 1352 (0x548 hex)
ld: 0711-310 ERROR: Relocation entries from the .text section have been
        written to the .loader section. The following csects are in error:
 CSECT or (Symbol in CSECT)   Inpndx  Address  TY CL Source-File(Object-File)
 Symbols referenced with .loader section RLDs: TY CL Inpndx  Name
 --------------------------------------------- -- -- ------------------------
 <_myCppFile.ro_>                   [260]   00004080 SD RO ../src/myCppFile.cpp(./build.AIX71_GCC_60300_64/myCppFile.cpp.1.o)
                                               ER PR [140]   __gcc_unwind_dbase
                                               SD RW [264]   <_myCppFile.rw_>
 <_myOtherCppFile.ro_>              [107]   00002240 SD RO ../src/myOtherCppFile.cpp(./build.AIX71_GCC_60300_64/myOtherCppFile.cpp.1.o)
                                               SD RW [111]   <_myOtherCppFile.rw_>
                                               ER PR [56]    __gcc_unwind_dbase
SAVE: The return code is 4.
(ld): rc
RC: Highest return code was 4.
```

A quick look at libgcc_s/libstdc++ shows that this symbol is defined and exported:

```
> nm -X64 /BUILD/SOFT/compilers/AIX71/GCC/60300/lib64/libgcc_s.a | grep __gcc_unwind
__gcc_unwind_dbase   D   536871816
__gcc_unwind_dbase   d   536871816           4
__gcc_unwind_dbase   d   536876288           8
> nm -X64 /BUILD/SOFT/compilers/AIX71/GCC/60300/lib64/libstdc++.a | grep __gcc_unwind
__gcc_unwind_dbase   D   536871608
__gcc_unwind_dbase   d   536871608           4
__gcc_unwind_dbase   d   537025144           8
```

What am I missing and doing wrong?
I precise that the result is the same regardless of which ld I use (system one --prefered-- or gnu binutils one)

**EDIT** When I create a dummy library and link an executable on it, everything went fine. The whole stuff is using the same options, except the external libraries used in the above quoted project. I am now completely stuck... T_T

Comment: Is that the *only* output the linker gives you? It sounds partial, that there was some previous output, and the "more information" bit is just telling you how to get more information about previous errors.

Comment: No more output is given but the 2 lines. As per the -bnoquiet option, you are right, this is a partial output. It starts from the step which causes error. I can put all the stuff if needed, but I found nothing helpfull inside.